# How does one hide a win32 app window?

Tags: c++, mfc, winapi

I want to run the app in silent mode by passing in a parameter, otherwise I will show the window.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ShowWindow(... SW_HIDE ...)` doesn't work?

The best practice here is to *not create the window in the first place*. Nothing forces you to actually create a window in InitInstance. Though if you're working with MFC it's likely a lot of your application/domain/business logic is sitting there, tightly coupled to those MFC message handlers and so forth. In which case the window will need to exist.

Comment: This is true, it is a clone of a legacy application to suite a similar but different need. There is too domain logic tied in there that I don't want to mess with because I will surely mess it all up.

Comment: I decided to bite the bullet and move a ton of code around. I ended up not creating the window in the first place when /silent is entered as a parameter. Thanks for the motivation!

Answer (score 6):

If you have an MFC `CWnd` based display then `CWnd::ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);`
If you are using just win32 then `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);`

Other things people do depending on your goals

- make the window very small
- move the window off the visible desktop area

Answer (score 3):

Well, for one you could just decide not to create a window at all if this parameter is passed in, otherwise you can try calling [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28VS.85%29.aspx), with the handle to your window and with the `SW_HIDE` parameter, and see if that does what you need.

Another way of hiding the window and never having it show up, but still create it, is to chose to never call `ShowWindow` with `SW_HIDE` on it, and create it with `CreateWindow`/`CreateWindowEx`, and not set the `WS_VISIBLE` flag in the `dwStyle` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better solution will be not creating the window if not needed.
Take a look at the main function and you will see the code that creates the window.
Call it only if you want to launch the window.

Comment: I really wish it was that simple.

Comment: but it is.
unless you have design problems and the logic is mix with the view.

Comment: It is legacy code with design problems and the logic is definitely mixed in with the view. I suppose I could separate the two, but then a full regression is needed and things will most certainly break.

Comment: How about if you are expecting to get messages to that window for IPC - not necessarily best way to do IPC, but a valid reason to have a window and not need it to be shown

Answer (score 1):

create the window, omit the WS_VISIBLE flag and don't call ShowWindow.

or

When you call showWindow(), add SW_HIDE parameter.

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```