# How to write a simple resident program in windows (or via Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

Maybe it is my English key word being wrong.

The "resident program" is a program would be zoom out in the hidden icon zone, if user press "close" or "minimized" button.

For example, the skype, audio control panel,  or (high-end) mouse adjustment panel would be resident program.

May Anyone give me a windows example or keyword for windows/Qt api ?

Comment: Did You try this to check, whether this covers Your topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016714/how-does-one-hide-a-win32-app-window

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is an English-only site.

Comment: The words in chinese is the same as English in concept..but be more brief.. Why my chinese words were deleted?

Comment: @GaigerChen Because this is, as I've said, an English-only site. You can ask questions in any other language elsewhere. SO would become an unbearable mess if everyone added their own favorite language translation in the questions and answers. If you think that there's potential for SO in Mandarin, you're more than welcome to spearhead that project on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). There is, for example, [SO in Portugese, in beta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 3):

The concept you're looking for is called the *system tray icon*. The `QSystemTrayIcon` class implements it portably.

Answer (score 1):

Small example as addition to first answer:

Somewhere in constructor:

```
tray = new QSystemTrayIcon();
tray->setIcon(QIcon("://data/tray.png"));
//tray->setContextMenu(menu);//you can also attach menu if you want
tray->show();
```

Closing:

In header:

```
    #include <QCloseEvent>
    #include <QMessageBox>
    #include <QSystemTrayIcon>
    //...
protected:
void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
private:
QSystemTrayIcon *tray;
```

In cpp:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    event->ignore();
    QMessageBox ms;
    ms.setText(tr("Are you sure?"));
    ms.setWindowTitle(tr("Title"));
    ms.setWindowIcon(QIcon("://data/tray.png"));
    ms.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
    QAbstractButton *y = ms.addButton("Quit",QMessageBox::YesRole);
    QAbstractButton *m = ms.addButton("Hide",QMessageBox::NoRole);
    QAbstractButton *n = ms.addButton("Cancel",QMessageBox::NoRole);
    ms.exec();
    if(ms.clickedButton() == y)
    {
            tray->hide();
            QCoreApplication::quit();
    }
    else
        if(ms.clickedButton() == m) this->hide();

}
```

Comment: @GaigerChen in this case if you found my and first answer useful, can you vote up it please(upper triangle pressing)? Also it will be very good when you choose the most useful answer for you and mark this answer as accepted. http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote