# How to run a exe without command prompt(GUI)?

Tags: c++

I've to run a executable, while system start-up automatically. For that I added the exe path in registry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
      Now the exe get started fine. but the command prompt also opened. so can I run the exe with silent mode, means without GUI.
      can I do it with c++ programming language?
      Or if there is any other way to do it possibly.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you are looking for "CreateProcess"? (see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @ChristianKiewiet not exactly. its exe have to be run on boot up time. so I think it is not suitable.

Comment: Try the Task Scheduler. If your program is not compiled as a console application, it should not spawn a console (unless AllocConsole is used)

Comment: if you creating a win 32 app you can hide your window using ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016714/how-does-one-hide-a-win32-app-window/31646000#31646000

Comment: If you configured your program as a console application, and you print output or try to get input, then the window will appear. You might try to create it as another type of executable project type.

Comment: Also, if you want your program to start at boot, you might want to create a Windows service instead?

Comment: It's baffling to me why you submitted the question with a random non-code code block at the bottom. Did you think that made sense?

Answer (score 1):

Do not link your application as a console application, but link it as a windows GUI application.

This way windows will not allocate a console for you, and you don't have to resort to hacks to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution you can hide the Console like that :

```
#include <windows.h>
...
int main()
{
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );
    ...
}
```

First you get a Handle to the Console, then you hide it

Comment: this is working good. nice idea. but first time command prompt comes up and then only hide.